# How to get the alternate dates between two dates in the same table and insert those dates into a temporary table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a question. I have a table like this:

[image: Table]

Actually, those dates are the start date and the end date of an employee who is working on a task. And in a month, usually they have more than one task.

What I want are the dates when they are idle or they don't have any task. So my question is, how to get those `idle` dates between those `working` dates and insert those `idle` dates into a temporary table?

Thank you :)

Comment: Can there be overlapping tasks for an employee? I mean, can he be working on two tasks at the same time, for example, task 1 from 1st oct to 3rd Oct and task 2 from 2nd Oct to 5th Oct)?

Comment: Have a look at [Packing Intervals](http://blogs.solidq.com/en/sqlserver/packing-intervals/) by Itzik Ben-Gan.

Comment: @Jayachandran yes, they can work on more than one task at the same time.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov the link cannot be open. do you have another link?

Comment: @SamuelLustrimanSihotang, their blog site must be down at the moment. You can still see it in the google's cache: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ICj_bROH8mcJ:blogs.solidq.com/en/sqlserver/packing-intervals/+&cd=5&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=au

Comment: @VladimirBaranov thank you for the link. after i read that article, i think it is the other way round. they "pack" the intervals but for my problem, i want to "unpack" the intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with SQL 2012 there's the [LEAD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) function.

It can be used to find gaps between ranges.

For example :

```
DECLARE @EmployeeAssignments TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1), EmployeeId INT, SDate DATE, EDate DATE);

INSERT INTO @EmployeeAssignments (EmployeeId,SDate,EDate) values 
(11505, '2016-10-01', '2016-10-05'),
(11505, '2016-10-09', '2016-10-12'),
(11505, '2016-10-14', '2016-10-20'),
(11506, '2016-10-02', '2016-10-05'),
(11506, '2016-10-08', '2016-10-14'),
(11506, '2016-10-15', '2016-10-19');

select *
from (
    select EmployeeId,
    dateadd(day,1,EDate) as StartDateGap,
    dateadd(day,-1,lead(SDate) over (partition by EmployeeId order by SDate)) as EndDateGap
    from @EmployeeAssignments
) as q
where StartDateGap <= EndDateGap
order by EmployeeId, StartDateGap, EndDateGap;
```

Returns:

```
EmployeeId StartDateGap EndDateGap
11505      2016-10-06   2016-10-08
11505      2016-10-13   2016-10-13
11506      2016-10-06   2016-10-07
```

To get those ranges as a list of dates?
One way to do that is by joining to a table with dates.

In the example below, a recursive query is used to generate those dates.
Only days between monday and friday are inserted.
Since we can expect that the employees would be idle on those days. ;)
But it's better to have a permanent table that also flags the holidays.

Also note that the first select on the @EmployeeAssignments is grouped.
Since the tasks cause a lot of duplicate date ranges.

```sql
DECLARE @EmployeeAssignments TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), EmployeeId INT, TaskId int, SDate DATE, EDate DATE);

INSERT INTO @EmployeeAssignments (EmployeeId, TaskId, SDate, EDate) values 
(11505,10,'2016-10-01','2016-10-05'),
(11505,12,'2016-10-09','2016-10-12'),
(11505,13,'2016-10-09','2016-10-12'),
(11505,14,'2016-10-14','2016-10-20'),
(11505,15,'2016-10-14','2016-10-20'),
(11506,16,'2016-10-02','2016-10-05'),
(11506,17,'2016-10-08','2016-10-14'),
(11506,18,'2016-10-15','2016-10-19');

DECLARE @Days TABLE (day DATE primary key);

declare @StartDate DATE = (select min(SDate) from @EmployeeAssignments);
declare @EndDate DATE = (select max(EDate) from @EmployeeAssignments);

-- fill up @Days with workingdays
with DAYS as (
    select @StartDate as dt
    union all
    select dateadd(day,1,dt)
    from DAYS
    where dt < @EndDate
)
insert into @Days (day)
select dt from DAYS
where DATEPART(dw, dt) in (2,3,4,5,6); -- dw 2 to 6 = monday to friday

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#EmployeeIdleDates') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #EmployeeIdleDates;
CREATE TABLE #EmployeeIdleDates (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) primary key, EmployeeId INT, IdleDate DATE);

insert into #EmployeeIdleDates (EmployeeId, IdleDate)
select 
a.EmployeeId, 
d.day as IdleDate 
from 
(
    select *
    from (
        select EmployeeId,
        dateadd(day,1,EDate) as StartDateGap,
        dateadd(day,-1,lead(SDate) over (partition by EmployeeId order by SDate)) as EndDateGap
        from (
            select EmployeeId, SDate, EDate 
            from @EmployeeAssignments 
            group by EmployeeId, SDate, EDate
            ) t
    ) as q
    where StartDateGap <= EndDateGap
) a
inner join @Days d 
   on (d.day between a.StartDateGap and a.EndDateGap)
group by a.EmployeeId, d.day;

select * from #EmployeeIdleDates 
order by EmployeeId, IdleDate;
```

Comment: it is working! thank you. but i have another question to ask. how about if i want to show the date gap in one column for each day in the gap, for example: 
2016-10-06
2016-10-07
2016-10-08
rather than showing the range of the date gap.

Comment: @SamuelLustrimanSihotang the answer has been updated for that.  This time even with inserts to a temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to work out is which dates have no corresponding time period in your source table.  The easiest way I have found to tackle this problem is with a [Dates table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/).  If you don't have one of these in your database already, I highly recommend it as having a table of every date you'll need with relevant metadata such as whether it is the start or end of the month, weekends, holidays, etc is incredibly useful.

If you can't create one of these, you can derive a simple one using a recursive cte and then return all dates that aren't represented in your source table *(This assumes you are reporting on one employee at a time)*:

```
declare @Tasks table(TaskID int
                    ,EmployeeID int
                    ,Sdate datetime
                    ,Edate datetime
                    )
insert into @Tasks values
 (1,1,'20160101','20160103')
,(2,1,'20160102','20160107')
,(3,1,'20160109','20160109')
,(4,1,'20160112','20160113')
,(5,1,'20160112','20160112')
,(1,2,'20160101','20160102')
,(2,2,'20160103','20160109')

declare @EmployeeID int = 1

declare @MinDate datetime = (select min(Sdate) from @Tasks where EmployeeID = @EmployeeID)
declare @MaxDate datetime = (select max(Edate) from @Tasks where EmployeeID = @EmployeeID)

;with cte as
(
    select @MinDate as DateValue

    union all

    select dateadd(d,1,DateValue) as DateValue
    from cte
    where DateValue < @MaxDate
)
select @EmployeeID as EmployeeID
    ,c.DateValue as DatesIdle
from cte c
    left join @Tasks t
        on(c.DateValue BETWEEN T.Sdate AND T.Edate)
where t.EmployeeID is null
order by DatesIdle
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how to solve this without unrolling the days within a Scope.
Hence I use a Tally table in this example.

I provide here an example of two Persons.
For debugging simplicity I use month units.

```
select top 100000 identity(int, 1, 1) as Id
into #Tally
from master..spt_values as a
cross join master..spt_values as b

declare 
    @ScopeB date = '2015-01-01',
    @ScopeE date = '2015-12-31'

declare @Task table
(
    TaskID int identity,
    PersonID int,
    TaskB date,
    TaskE date
)
insert @Task values
    (1, '2015-01-01', '2015-04-30'), -- Person 1 mth 1, 2, 3, 4
    (1, '2015-03-01', '2015-07-31'), -- Person 1 mth 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
    (2, '2015-01-01', '2015-03-31'), -- Person 2 mth 1, 2, 3
    (2, '2015-05-01', '2015-05-31'), -- Person 2 mth 5
    (2, '2015-09-01', '2015-11-30')  -- Person 2 mth 9, 10, 11

-- result: Person 1 free on mth 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
-- result: Person 2 free on mth 4, 6, 7, 8, 12

;
with
Scope as
(
    select dateadd(day, ID - 1, @ScopeB) as Dates
        from #Tally where ID <= datediff(day, @ScopeB, @ScopeE) + 1
        and datename(dw, dateadd(day, ID - 1, @ScopeB)) not in ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
),
Person as
(
    select distinct PersonID from @Task
),
Free as
(
    select p.PersonID, s.Dates from Scope as s cross join Person as p
    except
    select distinct t.PersonID, s.Dates from Scope as s cross join @Task as t
        where s.Dates between t.TaskB and t.TaskE
)
select PersonID, Dates, 
    datename(dw, Dates) from Free
    order by 1, 2

drop table #Tally
```

If you have a Holiday table, you can use it at the WHERE condition at the final SELECT as: `WHERE Dates NOT IN (SELECT Dates FROM Holiday)`.

Comment: Understood, was lazy. Fixed the Tally table population, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, please reconsider your approach to do this within the DB. The best place for data interpretation is at your application layer.

The below code will give you he gaps in the temp table @gaps. Of course, I have ignored irrelevant to the problem; you might want to add them. I used @temp in place of your table and inserted test values.

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (
    EmployeeID INT ,
    Sdate      DATE,
    Edate      DATE);

INSERT  INTO @temp
VALUES (11505, '2016-05-26', '2016-05-26'),
(11505, '2016-05-27', '2016-05-31'),
(11505, '2016-06-01', '2016-06-01'),
(11505, '2016-06-02', '2016-06-03'),
(11505, '2016-06-02', '2016-06-03'),
(11505, '2016-06-05', '2016-06-06'),
(11505, '2016-06-05', '2016-06-06'),
(11505, '2016-06-06', '2016-06-06'),
(11505, '2016-06-06', '2016-06-06'),
(11505, '2016-06-07', '2016-06-08'),
(11505, '2016-06-07', '2016-06-07'),
(11505, '2016-06-07', '2016-06-07'),
(11505, '2016-06-07', '2016-06-07'),
(11505, '2016-06-15', '2016-06-15'),
(11505, '2016-06-16', '2016-06-20'),
(21505, '2016-05-26', '2016-05-26'),
(21505, '2016-05-27', '2016-05-31'),
(21505, '2016-06-01', '2016-06-01'),
(21505, '2016-06-02', '2016-06-03'),
(21505, '2016-06-02', '2016-06-03'),
(21505, '2016-06-02', '2016-06-06'),
(21505, '2016-06-02', '2016-06-06'),
(21505, '2016-06-06', '2016-06-06'),
(21505, '2016-06-06', '2016-06-06'),
(21505, '2016-06-07', '2016-06-08'),
(21505, '2016-07-02', '2016-07-02'),
(21505, '2016-07-03', '2016-07-03'),
(21505, '2016-07-07', '2016-07-10'),
(21505, '2016-07-14', '2016-06-14'),
(21505, '2016-06-13', '2016-06-15');

DECLARE @emp AS INT;

DECLARE @start AS DATE;

DECLARE @end AS DATE;

DECLARE @EmployeeID AS INT, 
@Sdate AS DATE, 
@Edate AS DATE;

DECLARE @gaps TABLE (
    EmployeeID INT ,
    Sdate      DATE,
    Edate      DATE);

DECLARE RecSet CURSOR
    FOR SELECT   *
        FROM     @temp
        ORDER BY EmployeeID ASC, Sdate ASC, Edate DESC;

OPEN RecSet;

FETCH NEXT FROM RecSet INTO @EmployeeID, @Sdate, @Edate;

SET @emp = @EmployeeID;

SET @start = @Sdate;

SET @end = dateadd(day, 1, @Edate);

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        IF @Sdate <= @end
            BEGIN
                IF @Edate > dateadd(day, -1, @end)
                    BEGIN
                        SET @end = dateadd(day, 1, @Edate);
                    END
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                INSERT  INTO @gaps
                VALUES (@EmployeeID, @end, dateadd(day, -1, @Sdate));
                SET @start = @Sdate;
                SET @end = dateadd(day, 1, @Edate);
            END
        FETCH NEXT FROM RecSet INTO @EmployeeID, @Sdate, @Edate;
        IF @emp != @EmployeeID
            BEGIN
                SET @emp = @EmployeeID;
                SET @start = @Sdate;
                SET @end = dateadd(day, 1, @Edate);
            END
    END

CLOSE RecSet;

DEALLOCATE RecSet;

SELECT *
FROM   @gaps;
```

This gives @gaps as:

```
11505   2016-06-04  2016-06-04
11505   2016-06-09  2016-06-14
21505   2016-06-09  2016-06-12
21505   2016-06-16  2016-07-01
21505   2016-07-04  2016-07-06
21505   2016-07-11  2016-07-13
```